Is it grammatically correct to use the infinitive after the comparative adjective?
For example, if I say

It is more difficult than to strip the thorns off the tragacanth.

This is likely an Arabic proverb I found in one book of Google's. It means task A is more difficult than task B. OR something is ever impossible to be done.
The translation could be understood, but what if it is grammatically not correct.
Grammarians suggest using (that, other) after the conjunction "than". Some others say "than" is either conjunction or preposition. So, if we consider it a preposition, the gerund should follow not an infinitive. Hence, my correction to the above sentence will be as follows:

It is more difficult in achieving than that of stripping tragacanth thorns.

Please review what I said.

Grammar: It is more difficult than stripping the thorns off the tragacanth.

It is more difficult [to stay on top] than to get there; it is more difficult [to do only that which is moral] than to do anything you want to do. I'd say it was OK.

In comparisons, the tense of each element has to match. For example:

It is easier to do up a zipper than to sew on a button.

This example uses the infinitive and is fine.
Your direct translation doesn't contain two comparative elements. "It" in my example is a dummy pronoun that is just there to meet the grammatical requirement of having a subject. Quoted as it is, in your direct translation of this proverb "it" could only refer to a thing you have previously mentioned - the thing you are now comparing to. If the infinitive is the tense used in the other comparative element then technically you should match it.
In your example written sentence, you have brought two comparative elements together (although you don't actually say what you are trying to "achieve" - you still refer to "it" previously mentioned) but they do not match.
It should be:

It is more difficult to achieve than to strip tragacanth thorns.


How is it not included a comparative ? Even it is not visible, it is implied. A man told you  " doing this task is easier / more difficult  than doing that task. OR to do do this task is easier / more difficult than to do that task.  Nevertheless said,  I see it is possible to use the infinitive but we need to take the parallel structure into our consideration.

@AhmadMohammad I'd focused on your translation rather than you example. To be honest, asking "is this correct" is off-topic here so I was trying to avoid proof-reading your example and instead advising you on how to use the direct translation you quoted. But as you're struggling I've updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Thank you   I agree with your example.  I think you mean I remove of  ...

Thank you. I think you mean I remove  OF  plus THAT ... it = task  >> It is more difficult in achieving than stripping tragacanth thorns.   But as much as we learned is  to use  that or other after ( than).  However, I still need to ask a question :  It is more difficult to achieve than to strip tragacanth thorns.   To achieve what ?     The task is more difficult than stripping tragacanth thorns.   Anyway. I just asked to know whether using the infinitive is possible after than or not.   OK , it is possible


To get blood from a stone is easier than to get a simple answer from him.
It is easier to get blood from a stone than to get a simple answer from him.


Getting a simple answer from him is harder than getting blood from a stone.

The infinitival clause used nominally is somewhat old-fashioned compared to the participial/gerund version, but using the cleft structure gives the infinitival version a more contemporary syntax, a syntactical renovation, as it were.

@ TimR  Thank you
